# How to add CSS transition on closing event of a details tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

After reading those two questions:

- [How To Add CSS3 Transition With HTML5 details/summary tag reveal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213329/how-to-add-css3-transition-with-html5-details-summary-tag-reveal)
- [How to make <'details'> drop down on mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193606/how-to-make-details-drop-down-on-mouse-hover)

I have a new one for you!

**Problem**

I want an animation on closing event of the `<details>` tag. I thought that just revert the animation of opening would do the job, but unfortunately, no.

```js
$(function() {
  $('details').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).attr('open', true);
  }).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).attr('open', false);
  }).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

```css
details[open] SUMMARY~* {
  animation: sweepin .5s ease-in-out;
}

details[close] SUMMARY~* {
  animation: sweepout .5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes sweepin {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -10px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px
  }
}

@keyframes sweepout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -10px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Here my little summary</summary>
  <p>... Do you want more details?</p>
  <p>Here have some details!</p>
</details>
```

**Question**

Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can substitute toggling `.className` for `details[close]` selector; at `mouseover` event check if element is not `.open`, if `true`, set property to `.open = true` at `mouseout` event add `.className`, use `.one()` `animationend` event to remove `.className` and set `.open` to `false` at event handler.

```js
$(function() {
  $("details").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      if (!this.open && !$(this).is(".close"))
        $(this).prop("open", true)
        .one("animationend", function() {
          $(this).addClass("animationDone")
        })
    },
    mouseout: function _close() {
      if (!$(this).is(".close") && $(this).is(".animationDone"))
        $(this).addClass("close")
        .one("animationend", function() {
          $(this).prop("open", false)
          .removeClass("close animationDone")
        })
    },
    click: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
details[open] SUMMARY~* {
  animation: sweepin .5s ease-in-out;
}

details.close SUMMARY~* {
  animation: sweepout .5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes sweepin {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -10px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px
  }
}

@keyframes sweepout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -10px
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details>
  <summary>Here my little summary</summary>
  <p>... Do you want more details?</p>
  <p>Here have some details!</p>
</details>
```

Comment: it has a bug, if animation doesn't finish it doesn't remove the .close class .

Comment: @vlk How to reproduce bug?

Comment: try to move the mouse out before the animation is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for change the logic, but I've found this faster and fluid.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#summary').on('mouseover', function() {
  
    $('#triangleDown').fadeIn(0);
    $('#triangle').fadeOut(0);
    $('#content').addClass("open");
    
  }).on('mouseout', function() {
  
    $('#triangleDown').fadeOut(0);
    $('#triangle').fadeIn(0);
    $('#content').removeClass("open");
    
  })
  
});
```

```css
#triangleDown{
  display:none;
}

span{
  font-size: 12px;
}

#content{
  
  opacity:0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
  transition:all 1s;
  
}

#content.open{
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="summary"><span id="triangle">► </span><span id="triangleDown">▼ </span>Here my little summary</p>
  <div id="content">
  <p>... Do you want more details?</p>
  <p>Here have some details!</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an animation-fill-mode property to keep the original position of the div after animation is completed. On mouseover and mouse out event, you can add and remove the open and close attribute.

See snippet below

```js
$(function() {
  $('details').on('mouseover', function() {
   $(this).attr('open', true);
   $(this).removeAttr('close', false);


  }).on('mouseout', function() {
 
      $(this).attr('open', false);
            $(this).removeAttr('open', false);
            $(this).attr('close', true);
 


  }).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

```css
details[open] SUMMARY~* {
  animation: sweepin .5s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

details[close] SUMMARY~* {
  animation: sweepout .5s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes sweepin {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -10px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px
  }
}

@keyframes sweepout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -10px
  }
}
details{
border:solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br>
<details>
  <summary>Here my little summary</summary>
  <p>... Do you want more details?</p>
  <p>Here have some details!</p>
</details>
```